Passing parameters to anonymous javascript function in Blazor
I am building an app that requires the use of the TradingView advanced chart widget but I want to be able to pass a parameter into the options. This is what the code looks like from the website.
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container" style="height:100%;width:100%">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget" style="height:calc(100% - 32px);width:100%"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Track all markets on TradingView</span></a></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-advanced-chart.js" async>
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "COINBASE:BTCUSD",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "gridColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)",
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "calendar": false,
  "studies": [
    "STD;MACD"
  ],
  "support_host": "https://www.tradingview.com"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->

I want to be able to pass a parameter for the symbol: for example instead of "COINBASE:BTCUSD" i want it to be "COINBASE:+"@symbol+"" so it can be scalable and for some reason it breaks the code every time, and yes I did pay mind to the "" quotes, its just not passing my blazor variable. What can I do here? Here is the link to the widgets in case it helps: https://www.tradingview.com/widget-docs/widgets/charts/advanced-chart/ Any solution which can make these charts scalable across an entire application would be great

not sure if it'll help cause I never tried using script tags like that in blazor.
but check it like this: @($"COINBASE:{symbol}")

Nope :( there has to be some way of templating these widgets i know they can do it for react and its similar to blazor so theres got to be something

If anyone runs into this problem in blazor i solved it like this:
Chart.js
(function() 
{
    const charting = {
        show: function(symbol, locale, timezone, interval, showDetails, indicators) {
            new TradingView.widget({
                "autosize": true,
                "symbol": symbol,
                "interval": interval,
                "timezone": timezone,
                "theme": "light",
                "style": "8",
                "locale": locale,
                "gridColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06)",
                "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                "enable_publishing": false,
                "hide_top_toolbar": false,
                "allow_symbol_change": true,
                "save_image": false,
                "details": showDetails,
                "container_id": "tradingview_515f8",
                "studies": indicators,
                "studies": [
                    "STD;MACD",
                    "QuantNomad;UT Bot Alerts"
                ],
            });
        }
    };

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.charting = charting; // Make charting available globally if desired (optional)
    } else {
        // Provide module exports for bundlers or other environments (optional)
        module.exports = charting;
    }
})();

window.scriptLoader = function(sourceUrl, targetElement, innerHtml) {
    if (sourceUrl.Length == 0) {
        console.error("Invalid source URL");
        return;
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = sourceUrl;
    tag.type = "text/javascript";

    tag.onload = function () {
        console.log("Script loaded successfully");
    }

    tag.onerror = function () {
        console.error("Failed to load script");
    }
    tag.innerHTML = innerHtml
    const target = document.querySelector(targetElement);
    target.appendChild(tag);
};

window.pageLoader = function (sourceUrl) {
    window.location.href = sourceUrl;
}

ChartService.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace BotTrading.Services;

public class ChartService : IDisposable
{
    readonly IJSRuntime js;
    public readonly ChartConfig config;

    public readonly IEnumerable<string> symbolTypes = new[] { "all", "stock", "futures", "forex", "crypto", "index", "bond", "economic" };

    public readonly IEnumerable<string> Indicators = new[] {
        "STD;MACD",
        "UT Bot Alerts-QuantNomad",
    };

    public IEnumerable<(string, string)> Intervals = new[]
    {
        ("1", "1m"),
        ("3", "3m"),
        ("5", "5m"),
        ("15", "15m"),
        ("30", "30m"),
        ("60", "1h"),
        ("120", "2h"),
        ("180", "3h"),
        ("240", "4h"),
        ("D", "1d"),
        ("W", "1w"),
    };

    public ChartService(IJSRuntime js, ChartConfig config)
    {
        this.js = js;
        this.config = config;
        config.PropertyChanged += DrawChartSync;
    }

    private void DrawChartSync(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawChart();
    }

    public async Task DrawChart() => 
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("charting.show", config.Symbol.Id, config.Locale, config.TimeZone, config.Interval, config.ShowDetails, config.Indicators);
    
    public async Task DisplayChart(string symbol) => 
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("charting.show", symbol, config.Locale, config.TimeZone, config.Interval, config.ShowDetails, config.Indicators);

    public async Task Navigate(Uri uri) => 
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("pageLoader", uri);

    const string technicalAnalysisJsUrl = "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js";
    
    public async Task LoadTechnicalAnalysis(string containerElement) =>
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("scriptLoader", technicalAnalysisJsUrl, containerElement, JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            interval = "1m",
            width = "100%",
            height = "100%",
            isTransparent = false,
            symbol = config.Symbol.Symbol,
            showIntervalTabs = false,
            locale = config.Locale,
            colorTheme = "dark",
        }));

    // public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchTimeZones(string searchText) =>
    //     TimeZoneConverter.TZConvert
    //         .KnownIanaTimeZoneNames
    //         .Where(tz => tz.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
    //         .OrderBy(tz => tz);

    public void Dispose() =>
        config.PropertyChanged -= DrawChartSync;
}

ChartConfig.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using DevExpress.Mvvm.CodeGenerators;

namespace BotTrading.Services;

[GenerateViewModel]
public partial class ChartConfig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [GenerateProperty] ExchangeSymbol symbol = new ExchangeSymbol {Symbol = "XBTUSD"};
    [GenerateProperty] string locale = "en";
    [GenerateProperty] string timeZone = "Etc/UTC";
    [GenerateProperty] string interval = "240";
    [GenerateProperty] bool showDetails = false;
    [GenerateProperty] string[] indicators = Array.Empty<string>();

    public event EventHandler OnChartChanged =
        (sender, args) => { };

    public void Updated() =>
        OnChartChanged.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}


public record ExchangeSymbol
{
    public string Id => $"{Exchange}:{Symbol}";
    public string Symbol { get; init; }
    public string Description { get; init; }
    public string Type { get; init; }
    public string Exchange { get; init; }
    public string Provider_id { get; init; }
}

